# Multiplying arrays with scalars and adding in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have two columns of data in an excel sheet that are equal in size and both only contain numbers.

I'm trying to write a macros which will put both of these sets  into arrays, then perform a calculation on them. Specifically `ArrayA + 3*ArrayB` then put the result back into the worksheet in a new column.  Below is the code I have so far.

```
Dim ArrayA As Variant
Dim ArrayB As Variant
Dim ArrayC As Variant

ArrayA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5")
ArrayB = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B5")

'this is where things go bad
ArrayC = ArrayA + 3 * ArrayB
```

Comment: can you post what the error message is? I'm also wondering if you need to do Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value to specify the value of the range

Comment: You cannot multiply arrays like that in VBA. Are you just looking to calculate C=A+3B for each pair of values in arrays A and B? If so then you'd need to loop through the arrays and perform that calculation.

Answer (score 3):

YOu need to first make an array of values. Then be sure that you'r elooping htrough the arrays.

```
Dim ArrayA As Variant
Dim ArrayB As Variant
Dim ArrayC() As Variant

ArrayA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value
ArrayB = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B5").Value

'this is where things go bad
'ArrayC = ArrayA + 3 * ArrayB

'manually make array C the same size as array A
ReDim ArrayC(LBound(ArrayA, 1) To UBound(ArrayA, 1), 1 To 1)

Dim i As Long 'variable to count which section of the array we are on

' loop through each spot int he array and perform the math
For i = LBound(ArrayA, 1) To UBound(ArrayA, 1)
    ArrayC(i, 1) = ArrayA(i, 1) + 3 * ArrayB(i, 1)
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C5").Value = ArrayC
```

**Note** The above code is untested so I may have a typo in it somewhere. Also, you may need to declare ArrayC's data type instead of variant when using redim. I am unable to test at the moment as i'm answering from my mobile phone.

Comment: When you read a range into an array, it creates a two dimensional array even if the range has only one row or column.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I only ever read in using 2 dimensions so I wasnt aware that 1 wouldn't work.